# is it possible to put an image in a Treeview tkinter Python? not only in the first column

Tags: python, image, tkinter, treeview

Bonjour
Is there a way to put an image to replace a value in a tkinter treeview?
for exemple, instead of writing DEL, I want to put a trash basket or something like that?

I found no tutorial about my concern, maybe it is impossible, if it is the cas, what kind of windget should I use?

thank you in advance

David

Thanks for the answer.. I was telling myself, if I do not find any tutorial, maybe I cannot achieve my goal.

Here is a code example of what I want to do: instead of having the "[del]", I wanted to replace it with a nice image...

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")

tree = ttk.Treeview(root, selectmode=BROWSE, show='headings', height=100)

tree["column"] = ("#", "Nom", "Age", "DELETE", "Id")

tree.column('#0', width=0, stretch=NO)
tree.column('#1', minwidth=50, width=50, stretch=NO, anchor=CENTER)
tree.column('#2', stretch=NO, minwidth=220, width=150)
tree.column('#3', stretch=NO, minwidth=190, width=100)
tree.column('#4', stretch=NO, minwidth=100, width=70, anchor=CENTER)
 tree.column('#5', stretch=NO, width=0)

tree.heading("#0", text="")
tree.heading("#1", text="#", anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading("#2", text="Nom")
tree.heading("#3", text="Age")
tree.heading("#4", text="DELETE", anchor=CENTER)
tree.heading("#5", text="Id")

tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(1, "David", "32", "[del]", 1))
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(2, "Marius", "45", "[del]", 2))
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(3, "Aline", "25", "[del]", 3))
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(4, "Albert", "27", "[del]", 4))
tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(5, "Sophie", "38", "[del]", 5))

tree.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

If I cannot do it with Tkinter, what kind of thing may I use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to put an image in a Treeview tkinter Python? not only in the first column

No, it is not.

> if it is the cas, what kind of windget should I use?

Without knowing what you actually need to do, it's hard to say. You can either add images with labels to a grid, or add images in a text widget, or you could use a canvas. All of those accept images.